# Como garantir inserção e update de dados em diferentes bases de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, api

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação com uma arquitetura microservices e surgiu-me uma dúvida.
Cada funcionalidade da aplicação terá uma API isolada, como posso garantir que ao fazer um insert/update na base de dados da funcionalidade x, faz também um insert/update na base de dados da funcionalidade y?
* Assumindo que estas funcionalidades podem estar locais separados assim como as bases de dados.

Answer (score 1):

É um problema complicado de garantir uma solução perfeita. Procure pelo "Problema dos Generais Bizantinos".

Uma forma de solucionar de forma bastante satisfatória é usar a técnica de "two-phase commit" , ou commit em 2 fases. Na primeira fase, você invoca uma API de pre-commit. Se todos os serviços retornarem sucesso na fase de pre-commit, invoca-se uma segunda API (em cada um deles) efetivando o commit.

Ainda poderia haver uma falha no chamador, de modo que o commit definitivo seja invocado em apenas uma parte dos serviços remotos, mas pode-se adotar técnicas mitigatórias para isto (e.g. anotar todas as operações pendentes num journal ou registro em disco antes de invocar, e remover do journal apenas quando todas forem invocadas. Se o chamador quebrar no meio da lista de commits, ele refaz os commits quando rodar novamente.)

Seja como for, o fato é que as APIs remotas precisam fornecer a ferramenta básica, que é o commit em 2 fases. Os serviços remotos precisam ser pensados de forma a, uma vez que o pre-commit foi aprovado, o commmit final nunca pode falhar.